# I cannot ping/connect my VM on VMware Workstation

Tags: windows, networking, vmware-workstation

So I have a Windows 10 PC. I have installed VMware Workstation and created a Windows 10 VM. However, I cannot ping or connect to it. I have made the network  in bridged mode and given the same gateway. Anyone can help me?

Windows 10 PC ( Host )[image]

Windows 10 (Virtual Machine)
[image]

Network Setting for VM

[image]

In my view, since they are on same Gateway with bridged, they should connect. Can anyone help? ( Firewall is off )

Comment: Have you checked [this KB article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1007250)?

Comment: execute "netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8 enable" on both host and virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason for Windows not answering ping is its firewall.
Disable the VM firewall.

Comment: That's pretty heavy handed for just ping access.  Better to allow icmp than turn off the entire firewall

Comment: Agreed! But depends on the use case. If you are just doing labs and want to test network connectivity with ping, that's an easy way.

Comment: Imagine the actual reason being that your wifi roamed to another network so NATed and firewalled, that I *eventually* figured out even the host couldn't be pinged back.